# Trigger for specific class elements each when DOM ready on Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I have a list of data with the class of "shop". When DOM is ready I want to fire the trigger for each element with the class of "shop".

```
<section id="shops">
  <div class="shop" shop-key="{{ad.shopKey}}" ng-repeat="ad in ads">{{ad.shopName}}</div>
</section>
```

My DOM Element Variable: (shopKey)

```
"Selection Method": "CSS Selector"
"Element Selector": "#shops .shop"
"Attribute Name": "shop-key"
```

My Trigger:

```
"Trigger Type": "Page-View-Dom Ready"
"This trigger fires on": "Some DOM Ready Events"
"Conditions": "shopKey - does not equal - null"
```

But it fires only once. (For the first element with class of "shops").

How can I fire that trigger for all elements with that specific class?